# download html file instead of main file

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

i'm using android download manager to download a mp3 file, here is my code:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            String link = "https://newtabs.stream/HvWBZB:2nr2rB";
            Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(link);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");
            request.setTitle("GadgetSaint Downloading " + "Sample" + ".png");
            request.setDescription("Downloading " + "Sample" + ".png");
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/Songs/genesis" + ".mp3");

            long refid = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

download link for mp3 file: https://newtabs.stream/HvWBZB:2nr2rB

but the problem is that the downloaded file is actually a html source of a website (this site -> https://my-free-mp3.net)

i opened the download link in chrome and i got this log :
[headers for get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq7U4.png)

then i redirected to home page (https://my-free-mp3.net)

i also tried with IDM (internet download manager) and the same thing happened (home page html file)

but if you use the site and search for song every thing works fine AND AFTER THIS if you open download link in IDM it will recognize mp3 file.

(to download from website :
1- open https://my-free-mp3.net
2- search "genesis dua lipa"
3- click on download button in first result
4- then you will be redirected to safeURl.net, after that click on "Enter" button
5- download starts.
)

when i used website for downloading the same mp3 file i got this log : [headers for get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oi3g.png)

what should i do to make it work?

(the program that i'm using for getting those logs is "Live HTTP Headers". it's a google chrome extension. its really useful :)
[Live Http Headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/eaiimeeggnhceafhencnejheejddlcpa?hl=en)

Comment: The URL is actually a redirect URL through another service. As such, every time you try to get this page, it will only get you the html page.
To get the original MP3, you will need to get the link the site is redirecting to. It should end with a `.mp3` extension.

Comment: i used to download from this site for 2 months with these kinda links and every thing worked fine, i'm sure there is nothing wrong with the link, maybe a cookie or authorization is needed ...

Comment: It's possible. But from what I noticed, it has ads in the redirect page. Which means the get request will probably fetch the html of the ads page.